# Child object free movement on Parent object

Tags: c++, character, unreal

Just to be straightforward, I am completely new to many aspects of coding and am searching for different specs and guidelines to aid me on my journey to crafting a *wonderful* game in Epic Games' **Unreal Engine 4**.

Okay, I know upon viewing this, some may have little to no clue what I mean, so I'll put it like this to explain what I mean :

Imagine a **third person game** with a simple model of a character. Now, say I have an **object as a torso** of a character in a game. Now Say I have an **object as a head** of the character. How could I **keep the head as a child of the torso**, but at the same time, allow it to **move with the camera angle**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you need is to create a `Player` object that will allow you to set up players position and orientation. Next, connect a `Torso` object as a child of `Player` so it moves and rotates with your main object.

Then connect a `Head` as the child of `Torso` so it moves with `Torso`, but can rotate in its own local space, so you can rotate a `Player` head.

At the end connect a `Camera` as a child of the `Head` and move it backward by some amount. This way a `Camera` will be always at some distance from the `Head`, looking at it, regardless of the `Head` orientation.